# Laravel - validate an indexed array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a validator that looks like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($shipment, [
        'collection_date' => 'required|date',
        "parcels"    => "required|array|min:1",
        "parcels.*.items" => "required|array",
        "parcels.*.items.*.value" => "required"
    ]);
```

Now looking at this, it's easy to see that parcels should be an array, and each parcel should have a property `items`, and that should be an array, and each item should have a property `value`.

However what I'm getting is, instead of someone passing it through like you'd expect,

`[parcels:[{items:[{value:1}]}]]`,

They're passing it like this:

`[parcels:[{items:{value:1}}]]`

When there's only one item. The validator is failing, as I want it to of course, but the message is quite weird because it's actually seeing `items` as an array, even though it's actually an associative array rather than a list of items.

So the message says something like `error: parcels.0.items.values has no property value` -- I don't remember exactly what it says, I just know that it obviously tried to access 'value' as if it was a member of the 'items' array (because technically it is! just not in the way I want).

Whereas what I'd really want it to say is something like `error: parcels.0.items was not supplied as an array`

Comment: show me your main array. with sub arrays

Comment: For provide correct answer you should include your main array.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that comes to mind would be adding a custom error message for your rule:

```
$messages = [
    'parcels.*.items.array' => ':attribute was not supplied as an array',
];

$validator = Validator::make(
             $shipment, 
             [ 
              'collection_date' => 'required|date',
              "parcels"    => "required|array|min:1",
              "parcels.*.items" => "required|array",
              "parcels.*.items.*.value" => "required"
              ],
              $messages
           );
```

You can find more detailed information about custom error messages in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages).

Answer (score 0):

Use custom error message for displaying it. Your code be like

```
$validator = Validator::make($shipment, [
    'collection_date' => 'required|date',
    "parcels"    => "required|array|min:1",
    "parcels.*.items" => "required|array",
    "parcels.*.items.*.value" => "required"
],
[
    'parcels.*.items.array' => 'Your custom error msg which you want to display',
]);
```